# How golang applies less than and greater than operators to strings?

Tags: string, go, string-comparison

I'm wondering if only the length of the strings is being compared, or the lexical order is also considered.
If anyone knows where it can be viewed in the code - I would be grateful for the link!

Comment: This would be a very simple test to write yourself

Comment: Length is only compared when testing for equality (`=`) (as a "shortcut" test for telling if they are not equal), for less than and greater than, length has no significance. Bytes of the strings are compared until a difference is found. [Spec: Comparison operators:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) _"Two string values are compared lexically byte-wise."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Go, strings can be compared using comparison operators like < and >. Here is how string comparison works in Go:

Strings are compared byte-by-byte based on the UTF-8 encoding of the string. The comparison is done lexicographically, which means comparing string byte values from left to right.
For example:

```
"a" < "b" // true
"hello" < "hello world" // true
"" > "Hello" // true
```

When comparing two strings of different lengths, the shorter string is logically padded with null bytes during comparison. So a shorter string is always "less" than a longer string if the common prefix is identical.

```
"hello" < "hello world" // true (hello padded with null bytes) 
"hello" < "hellp" // true (o is before p)
```

The null character `\x00` is considered the lowest value byte. So any string starting with a null byte would be "less" than any non-empty string.

Overall, this lexicographical byte-by-byte comparison allows strings to be easily sorted and compared in Go based on Unicode/UTF-8 encoding. The rules are simple - compare bytes from left to right, with null bytes considered the lowest values.

Comment: "Hello" starts with an 'H', and "" is an emoji, a single Unicode character. Unicode values for normal alphabetic characters are less than those for emojis. 'H' has a Unicode value of 72, while "" (APPLE) has a Unicode value of 127822. Therefore, 72 is less than 127822, so "Hello" is less than "". Thus, "" > "Hello" is true